# Convert Apache mod_proxy [P] to Nginx equivalent

Tags: nginx

We have this working in Apache. You can see [here](http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cbQrFpI0S9).

The `$request_uri`

```
/h_32/w_36/test.jpg
```

needs to be routed to

```
/index.php/img/i/h_32/w_36/test.jpg
```

`index.php` will route the request to the `img` controller and `i` method, then process the image and return it. However, my MVC works off of the `REQUEST_URI`. So simply rewriting the url will not work. The `REQUEST_URI` needs to be modified.

You can see in the last location block that I pass in the modified `REQUEST_URI`, but Nginx is trying to open `/var/www/vhosts/ezrshop.com/htdocs/h_32/w_36/test.jpg` (see **Error Logs** below) and throwing a 404.

Shouldn't Nginx be trying to send it for processing to `index.php`?? Why the 404?

```
root /var/www/vhosts/example.com/htdocs;
index index.php index.html;

set $request_url $request_uri;

location ~ (h|w|fm|trim|fit|pad|border|or|bg)_.*\.(jpg|png)$ {
    if ($request_uri !~ "/img/i/") {
            set $request_url /index.php/img/i$1.$2;
    }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/img/i$1.$2;
}

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri?$args;
}

location ~ ^(.+\.php)(.*)$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  CI_ENV production; #CI environment constant
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI $request_url;
}
```

**Error Logs:**

**Log 1:**

```
/img/i/ does not match /h_32/w_36/test.jpg, request: GET /h_32/w_36/test.jpg HTTP/1.1
```

**Log 2:**

```
open() "/var/www/vhosts/ezrshop.com/htdocs/h_32/w_36/test.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), request: "GET /h_32/w_36/test.jpg HTTP/1.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution.

```
root /var/www/vhosts/example.com/htdocs;
index index.php index.html;

location ~ ^/(h|w|fm|trim|fit|pad|border|or|bg)_.*\.(jpg|png)$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    # route to /img/i/
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI /img/i$uri;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_param CI_ENV production; #CI environment constant
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri?$args;
}

location ~ ^(.+\.php)(.*)$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  CI_ENV production; #CI environment constant
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Good that you found the solution, once I pointed you to the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following approach:

```
location ~* ^/_img/(h|w|fm|trim|fit|pad|border|or|bg)(_.+\.)(jpg|png)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/img/i/$1$2$3?$args;
}
```

We use the regex in the `location` directive to capture the parts we want into the variables, and then we use those variables for the rewrite.

Since the `location` regex is defined in such a detailed way, it won't match the rewritten location. However, here we pass the changed URL directly to `try_files`.

Comment: [DOCUMENT_URI] => /index.php/img/i/h_32/w_36/test.jpg
[REQUEST_URI] => /_img/h_32/w_36/test.jpg

You can see the REQUEST_URI, which routing is based off of in my app is not changing. That's why I'm trying to go the proxy_pass route.

Comment: Then you have to include statements from `fastcgi_params` into the `location` block and re-define the `REQUEST_URI` there.

Comment: Okay, I've tried both suggestions. Still getting 404's. What am I doing wrong? Will you please provide an example of setting the REQUEST_URI either the try_files route or the proxy_pass route? I thought proxy pass would be the way to go since it will send a new request.

Comment: Any thoughts on my latest edit? I feel like I'm getting close.